# Package Control no module named package_control.add_repository_channel_command

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, sublimetext3, package-control

I've updated to the most recent version of Package Control for Sublimetext 3 via Git, but none of the commands work.  The menu items are still present, strangely enough.  When I open the log with `` Ctrl+` ``, I see this error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'Package Control.package_control.add_repository_channel_command'
```

How can I get it to work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the Package Control `.sublime-package` file is outdated, and in this case, referencing a python module that has been moved to a different python package (from `package_control` to `package_control.commands`).

This can be easily fixed by deleting `Installed Packages/Package Control.sublime-package`.

Answer (score 0):

I use sublime text 3

[From this site](https://www.granneman.com/webdev/editors/sublime-text/packages/how-to-install-and-use-package-control/), I Follow these steps:

1. Go to http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation
   & copy the long command there.
2. Open the Sublime Text 2 console by
   pressing `Ctrl+`.
3. Paste the command you copied into the Sublime Text
   console.
4. Press Enter.
5. After Package Control installs, restart
   Sublime Text.

Then I got the error like that.

I have tried :

check `ignored_packages` on set but I found nothing.

Download package manager and copy it to `Installed Packages`, but not works.

Then I update my sublime to the newest version, then the error is gone.

That is my tips, you should try one of the steps, like what I have tried.